# Best way to sort through running apps that have UI | Swift3, macOS

Tags: macos, swift3, macos-sierra

So I have an app that analyses the running apps, my code so far

```
func running() -> [NSRunningApplication]{
    let base = NSWorkspace()
    let apps = base.runningApplications
    return apps
}

for app in running() {
    print(app.localizedName)
    print("isActive: \(app.isActive) | isHidden: \(app.isHidden) | ")

}
```

I can determine lots of properties [image: properties]. However I want to filter apps that have UI kind of like the ones in the Force Quit Applications menu:[image: fca menu]

So any tips on how to filter these apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter for `activationPolicy == .regular`

```
let apps = base.runningApplications.filter {$0.activationPolicy == .regular}
```

Source: [NSApplicationActivationPolicy](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsapplicationactivationpolicy)